# How to get the current file name in plugin action class

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In the IntelliJ IDEA plugin action class, I want to get the Java class file name which user is currently viewing.  How would I get that?

In IntelliJ IDEA, if we click `Analyse -> Inspect Code`, it will show a window to choose scope, in that it will show the current file name also. Similar to that view, I want to get the current file name in plugin action class. How could I do that?

Comment: [This might help you](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5110846#5110846), but it may be a bit outdated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  public class MyAction extends AnAction {
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
      VirtualFile vFile = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE);
      String fileName = vFile != null ? vFile.getName() : null;
    } 
  }
```